# Problema con el uso de la función COUNT MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Buen día,

Tengo 6 tablas relacionadas (eventos, eventos_servicios, servicios, detalle_compra, recibo) que están de la siguiente manera:

**eventos**

```
-----------------------------
| id_evento | nombre_evento |
-----------------------------
|     1     |    evento 1   |
-----------------------------
|     2     |    evento 2   |
-----------------------------
|     3     |    evento 3   |
-----------------------------
```

**servicios**

```
---------------------------------
| id_servicio | nombre_servicio |
---------------------------------
|      1      |    servicio 1   |
---------------------------------
|      2      |    servicio 2   |
--------------------------------
|      3      |    servicio 3   |
---------------------------------
```

**participantes**

```
-----------------------------------------
| id_participante | nombre_participante |
-----------------------------------------
|        1        |       nombre 1      |
-----------------------------------------
|        2        |       nombre 2      |
-----------------------------------------
|        3        |       nombre 3      |
-----------------------------------------
|        4        |       nombre 4      |
-----------------------------------------
```

**eventos_servicios**

```
------------------------------------------------
| id_evento_servicio | id_evento | id_servicio |
------------------------------------------------
|          1         |    1      |     1       |
------------------------------------------------
|          2         |    1      |     2       |
------------------------------------------------
|          3         |    1      |     3       |
------------------------------------------------
```

**detalles_compras**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id_detalle_compra | id_evento_servicio| id_recibo |
-----------------------------------------------------
|         1         |         1         |     1     |
-----------------------------------------------------
|         2         |         1         |     2     |
-----------------------------------------------------
|         3         |         2         |     2     |
-----------------------------------------------------
|         4         |         3         |     3     |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

**recibos**

```
------------------------------------------------
| id_recibo | id_participante | estatus_recibo |
------------------------------------------------
|     1     |        1        |       1        |
------------------------------------------------
|     2     |        2        |       2        |
------------------------------------------------
|     3     |        3        |       2        |
------------------------------------------------
```

Y yo hago la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT e.id_evento, e.nombre_evento, r.estatus_recibo
FROM eventos e
JOIN eventos_servicios es ON e.id_evento = es.id_evento
JOIN servicios s ON es.id_servicio = s.id_servicio
JOIN detalle_compras dp ON es.id_evento_servicio = dp.id_evento_servicio
JOIN recibos r ON dp.id_recibo = r.id_recibo
JOIN participantes p ON r.id_participante = p.id_participante
WHERE e.id_evento = 1
GROUP BY r.id_recibo
```

Lo que quiero logar, es contar determinados estatus (puede ser 1, 2, 3) que hay en cada evento separado por recibo, pues el participante no se puede registrar en el mismo evento dos veces.

Por ejemplo, que me devuelva cuantas personas diferentes hay en el evento 1 con el estatus igual a 1 del recibo 2.

Ya lo intente de varias maneras, sin embargo, no lo logro.
Espero me haya explicado y me puedan ayudar.

De antemano muchas gracias.

**Actualización 1**

Ejemplo:
5 participantes están registradas en el mismo evento y quisiera saber cuantas personas de ese evento tienen el atributo "estatus_recibo" en valor 1.

Tabla recibos

```
------------------------------------------------
| id_recibo | id_participante | estatus_recibo |
------------------------------------------------
|     1     |        1        |       1        |
------------------------------------------------
|     2     |        2        |       1        |
------------------------------------------------
|     3     |        3        |       2        |
------------------------------------------------
```

En esta tabla, debería de contar que hay participantes 3 con el "estatus_recibo = 1"

**Actualización 2**
De como espero la respuesta de la consulta base a la información que puse en la tabla en la primera actualización.
Donde la condición sería estatus_recibo = 1

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id_evento | nombre_evento | COUNT(estatus_recibo) |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     1     |    evento 1   |           2           |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

**O**
Donde la condición sería estatus_recibo = 2

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id_evento | nombre_evento | COUNT(estatus_recibo) |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     1     |    evento 1   |           1           |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

El detalle es que si en el evento se registraron 2 personas, de los cuales el primero se registro en dos servicios y el segundo en 3, al hacer un COUNT en el atributo estatus_recibo con la condición que sea igual a 1 me da 5, que cuando debería darme 2 (Si en la cláusula WHERE uso "estatus_recibo = 1") o debería darme 1 (Si en la cláusula WHERE uso "estatus_recibo = 2")

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Esto es confuso: *Por ejemplo, que me devuelva cuantas personas diferentes hay en el evento 1 con el estatus igual a 1 del recibo 2.*  ¿Podrías explicarlo mejor y dar un ejemplo si es posible?

Comment: Listo, al final coloque una actualización, espero haya sido un poco mas claro. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Agrega por favor un ejemplo de como queres que queden tus datos. por lo que veo, solo necesitas un count de id_participante agrupado por estatus_recibos?

Comment: Ya puse un ejemplo de como espero la consulta. Espero me haya hecho entender. Saludos

Comment: Poner como nombre de columna el estado si que va a ser muy complicado. el resto es trivial. Seguro que necesitas eso?

Comment: Ya modifique la actualización 1 y 2. Disculpa, soy muy malo dándome a entender. lo que estaba entre comillas era la condicional de la cláusula WHERE (estatus_recibo = 1, por dar un ejemplo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo suelo recomendar para estas cosas, y cuando se esta aprendiendo, hacerlas por pedazos, ya que asi es mucho mas facil entender que pasa y que resultados vamos obteniendo.

Asi que hagamosla por pedazos (aunque no sea lo mas optimo) pero asi entendemos el problema...

El resultado que buscamos es por cada evento, la cuenta de estatus_recibos.

Para esto, arranquemos por traer todos los eventos:

```
Select id_evento,id_servicio 
From eventos_servicios
```

Bien.. ahora a esta tabla.. tendriamos que pegarles los recibos.. pero no los tenemos, asi que saltemos de tabla en tabla hasta traerlos.

```
Select id_evento,id_servicio 
From eventos_servicios e inner join detalles_compras d on 
    e.id_evento_servicio = d.id_evento_servicio
```

Con esto, traemos los recibos.. pero no sabemos su estado.. agreguemoslo...

```
Select a.*, r.estatus_recibo  
From (
Select id_evento,id_servicio 
From eventos_servicios e inner join detalles_compras d on 
    e.id_evento_servicio = d.id_evento_servicio) a inner join
recibos r on a.id_recibo = r.id_recibo
```

Ahora, ya tenemos la lista que queremos, y solo tenemos que agruparla por el campo que querramos.

```
Select id_evento, count(estatus_recibo)
from (TODO LO ANTERIOR)
group by estatus_recibo
```

Si solo necesitamos algun caso, entonces deberiamos agregar un where

```
Where estatus_recibo = ?
```

Y si queremos agregar a eso, el nombre del evento, hagamos lo mismo, a esta ultima, unamosla a eventos, y listo!

Comment: Excelente, ¡justo lo que estaba buscando! Solo una duda más, en esta parte de la consulta "from (TODO LO ANTERIOR)" salia un error y me pedía nombrar la tabla, a lo que intuí que era ponerlo de la siguiente manera "from (TODO LO ANTERIOR) b..." ¿Estoy en lo correcto? Saludos.

Comment: No. Por todo lo anterior me referia a la consulta anterior, el select que habiamos escrito en el paso anterior

Comment: Si, comprendo esa parte, que era poner todo lo habías escrito en los pasos anteriores, y de la misma puse eso, para no escribir todo, me refería a que el administrador de BD que uso me dio un error, que nombrara el resultado y puse fuera del paréntesis la letra "b" y se resolvió el error, mi pregunta era, ¿fue correcto? (El error en concreto fue "Every derived table must have its own alias")

Comment: Si. es correcto.

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo en tiendo es que quieres lograr saber cuantos participantes hay por cada estatus en cada uno de los eventos una buena opción es teniendo en cuenta tu consulta solo faltaria agruparla también estatus_recibo y contarlos asi

```
SELECT e.id_evento, e.nombre_evento, r.estatus_recibo, COUNT(r.estatus_recibo) AS numero_participantes
FROM eventos e
JOIN eventos_servicios es ON e.id_evento = es.id_evento
JOIN detalle_compras dp ON es.id_evento_servicio = dp.id_evento_servicio
JOIN recibos r ON dp.id_recibo = r.id_recibo
JOIN participantes p ON r.id_participante = p.id_participante
WHERE e.id_evento = 1
GROUP BY r.id_recibo, r.estatus_recibo
```

tambien le borre servicios porque no se muestra en la consulta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, sin embargo, ya hice esta consulta y me mostraba datos de mas o de acuerdo a los servicios_eventos que adquirió. Y nuevamente gracias por haberte tomado el tiempo.